# Trying to set y axis labels and ticks aligned to 2D faces

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my plot:

[image]

If I were to draw your attention to the axis labelled 'B' you'll see that everything is not as it should be.

The plots was produced using this:

```
def newPoly3D(self):

    from matplotlib.cm import autumn

    # This passes a pandas dataframe of shape (data on rows x 4 columns)

    df = self.loadData() 

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    vels = [1.42,1.11,0.81,0.50] 
    which_joints = df.columns
    L = len(which_joints)
    dmin,dmax = df.min().min(),df.max().max()
    dix = df.index.values
    offset=-5
    for i,j in enumerate(which_joints):
        ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(dix,df[j],
                                             dmin,
                                             lw=1.5,
                                             alpha=0.3/float(i+1.),
                                             facecolor=autumn(i/float(L))),
                                             zs=vels[i],
                                             zdir='y')
    ax.grid(False)
    ax.set_xlabel('A') 
    ax.set_xlim([0,df.index[-1]])
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.set_axis_off
    ax.set_ylabel('B') 
    ax.set_ylim([0.4, max(vels)+0.075])
    ax.set_yticks(vels)
    ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=10)
    ax.set_zlabel('C') 
    ax.set_zlim([dmin,dmax])
    ax.xaxis.labelpad = -10
    ax.yaxis.labelpad = 15
    ax.zaxis.labelpad = 15
    # Note the inversion of the axis
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

- First I want to align the ticks on the yaxis (labelled B) with each coloured face. As you can see they are now offset slightly down.
- Second I want to align the yaxis tick labels with the above, as you cans see they are currently very much offset downwards. I do not know why.

EDIT:

Here is some example data; each column represents one coloured face on the above plot.

```
-13.216256  -7.851065   -9.965357   -25.502654
-13.216253  -7.851063   -9.965355   -25.502653
-13.216247  -7.851060   -9.965350   -25.502651
-13.216236  -7.851052   -9.965342   -25.502647
-13.216214  -7.851038   -9.965324   -25.502639
-13.216169  -7.851008   -9.965289   -25.502623
-13.216079  -7.850949   -9.965219   -25.502592
-13.215900  -7.850830   -9.965078   -25.502529
```

Here we are again, with a simpler plot, reproduced with this data:

```
k = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([range(k), 
                           [x + 1 for x in range(k)],
                           [x + 4 for x in range(k)], 
                           [x + 9 for x in range(k)]]).T,columns=list('abcd'))
```

[image]

If you want to try this with the above function, comment out the `df` line in the function and change its argument as so `def newPoly3D(df):` so that you can pass the the test `df` above.

Comment: The ticks misalignment seems to be a bug in 3d projection - the set_*limit* family methods are neither clipping the data nor position the spines to the limits. It may be also a feature.